# What does 她又自杀又下跪地被送上了飞机 mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

> 后来据说阿紫自己跑去医院打掉了孩子，她的家里人为了断绝她和仲嵚的来往，想办法把她弄去了法国，在亲戚家开的餐馆做帮厨，**她又自杀又下跪地被送上了飞机**。现在想来，这应该是这个故事里最圆满的一种解脱。
> <sub>仲尼, *谢谢你曾来过我的世界*, 2017, p.19 ([photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUw9T.jpg)).</sub>

I don't get what the part in bold above means.  Google Translate doesn't really help much:

> She committed suicide and knelt down and was put on the plane.

I also feel a bit weird about [the grammar structure 又……又……](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22both_A_and_B%22_with_%22you%22) being used with verbs (I thought [一边……一边……](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Simultaneous_tasks_with_%22yibian%22) was for verbs).  My guess is that it's related to the 据说, and that these are two simultaneous rumors about what happened to 阿紫.

**Question**: What does 她又自杀又下跪地被送上了飞机 mean?

Comment: It's not a good expression or writing though.

Comment: 又自杀又下跪 -- much like the phrase "kicking and screaming"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are an advanced Chinese learner/reader, I think you have seen this phrase before - "又哭又鬧", a person protest an unfavorable decision/order against him/her by crying out loud and making a scene/disturbance on the surroundings to draw attention.

In this case, the overall meaning is the same as the above, but instead of 哭和鬧, 阿紫 uses 自杀 and 下跪 to fight against the forced departure (she **both** threatens to kill herself **and** kneeling down to beg not to carry out the family decision).

Example phrases in the form of 又...又...

- 又跳又叫
- 又哭又笑
- 又抓又咬

Answer (score 2):

At that time, She didn't want to be sent to France， and expressed her attitude by begging (下跪) and threatening（自杀）.